# How do you assemble Map<Key, Value> from nested objects using Java8 stream?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Suppose I have 3 cars, each car having 3 engines, each engine having 3 parts.  How can I create a `map of <engine_model, List<parts>>` out of this using Java8 streams?

In regular java I would do the following:

```
Map<String, List<Parts>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Parts>>();
for (Car car: cars){
  for (Engine engine: car.getEngines()){
    if (!map.contains(engine.getModel())){
      map.put(engine.getModel(), new ArrayList<Part>());
    }
    for (Part  part: engine.getParts()){
      map.get(engine.getModel()).add(part);
    }
  }
}
```

here `map` is a `map` that maps the engine's model (`type String`) to the list of all the parts pertaining to that model.  different cars can have same engine model.

I tried to do the following:

```
carList.stream().flatMap(p -> p.getEngines().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getModel(),
               Collectors.mapping(Engine::getParts, Collectors.toList())))
```

the problem is that using above I am getting 
`Map<String, List<List<Part>>>`
and I want 
`Map<String, List<Part>>`

I guess an equivalent question would be:  how do I change the `List of Lists` to just `List` in the context of the above example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you can even simplify your imperative variant:

```
Map<String, List<Part>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Car car: cars) {
    for(Engine engine: car.getEngines()) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(engine.getModel(), key -> new ArrayList<>())
           .addAll(engine.getParts());
    }
}
```

That’s important when deciding whether the functional variant is really an improvement. The `flatMap` + `groupingBy` collector is the right approach, but the fact that you have a list (of `Part`s) to flatten is an additional obstacle. In Java 9, you could write

```
Map<String, List<Part>> map = cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Engine::getModel,
                 Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getParts().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```

But until then, we have to manually assemble an equivalent collector:

```
Map<String, List<Part>> map = cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Engine::getModel,
                 Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (l,e) -> l.addAll(e.getParts()),
                              (l1,l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; })));
```

So I would consider staying with the loop for now.

Comment: You are a `stream()` pro :D

Comment: Thanks, @Holger!!  Yes this is exactly what I needed and you actually cleared some things that I getting hung up on.  I am only making my first baby steps into the streams(), but it sure feels like a very powerful stuff.

Comment: Suggesting keeping the loop is actually the best part of the answer. Functional versions may be "cool", but are not always an improvement in readability/maintainability.